string.Contains doesn't work with some special string when comparing in Selenium
I have to compare a string from an element extracted from the Selenium with a string read from file. All the things work great, but when i need to compare between these 2 string, it doesn't work as expected:
string a = "a. Check map, Help, Activate function \"Robbery\""; // Read from file
string b = "Check map, Help, Activate function \"Robbery\""; // Extracted from Selenium

I have used Contains, IndexOf, Regex to check if string a contains string b, but all that return false. I have try to run it in a simple program outside my context and that return true.It only happen in the context when i run Selenium to extract text and compare with a string read from file. Am i wrong in comparing string in Selenium? I am sure that the above two strings are copied completely correctly, without any extra or missing words
My full code:
public static void DoSingleQuiz(string course, int mooc, int week)
{
    driver.Navigate().GoToUrl(CourseData.All[course]["MOOC" + mooc]["WEEK" + week]);

    // Click on continue button
    driver
        .FindElement(
            By.XPath("//*[@id=\"main\"]/div[1]/div[3]/div[1]/div[2]/div/div/div/div/div"),
            10000
        )
        .Click();

    var questions = driver.FindElements(By.ClassName("rc-FormPartsQuestion"), 10000);

    // The keys read from file
    var keys = Helper.ReadKey($"key/{course}DB/questions_and_keys.txt");

    foreach (IWebElement question in questions)
    {
        var questionText = question
            .FindElement(
                By.CssSelector(
                    "div:nth-child(1) > div.rc-FormPartsQuestion__contentCell p:nth-child(1)"
                )
            )
            .Text.Trim();
        Console.WriteLine("===================================================");
        Console.WriteLine($"testQs-{questionText}-");

        // Check if the current question extracted from Selenium already exist in my keys file or not
        var quesFound = keys.Find(key => key.Question.Contains(questionText));
        if (quesFound != null)
        {
            Console.WriteLine($"sheetQs-{quesFound.Question}-");
            Console.WriteLine($"sheetAns-{quesFound.Answer}-");
        }
        var answers = question.FindElements(By.ClassName("rc-Option"));
        foreach (IWebElement answer in answers)
        {
            // List all the key extracted from Selenium of current question
            Console.WriteLine($"testAns-{answer.Text.Trim()}-");
            if (quesFound != null && quesFound.Answer.Contains(answer.Text))
            {
                // Choose the answer that the key string contains it
                Console.WriteLine($"key-{answer.Text.Trim()}-");
                answer.Click();
            }
        }
    }
}

The keys is a List of Quiz object read from file:
   public class Quiz
   {
       public string Question { get; set; } = string.Empty;
       public string Answer { get; set; } = string.Empty;
   }
   internal class Helper
   {

       public static List<Quiz> ReadKey(string filepath)
       {
           List<Quiz> keys = new List<Quiz>();
           try
           {
               string[] lines = File.ReadAllLines(filepath);
               foreach (string line in lines)
               {
                   // Split each line by the pipe character
                   string[] parts = line.Split('|');

                   if (parts.Length == 2)
                   {
                       string question = parts[0].Trim();
                       string answer = parts[1].Trim();
                       key.Add(new Quiz()
                       {
                           Answer = answer,
                           Question = question
                       });
                   }
               }
           }
           catch (Exception ex)
           {
               Console.WriteLine($"Error reading file: {ex.Message}");
           }
           return keys;
       }
   }

questions_and_answer.txt
Which of the following are among key tasks that were identified?a. Check map, Help, Activate function "Robbery"b. Check map, Create a post, Log Outc. Customize automatic functions, Help, Log Outd. Change security code, Create a post, Check recent events | a. Check map, Help, Activate function "Robbery"
Could you run user tests with this prototype and receive useful data to inform your designs?a. Yes, any type of prototype can be used for user testingb. No, only fully interactive digital prototypes will give you useful datac. No, user testing is most effective when you use hand-drawn prototypes rather than ones created with graphic design softwared. No, you shouldn't use a prototype to conduct user testing | a. Yes, any type of prototype can be used for user testing
This example would most likely be an example of (choose the BEST response):a. Wireframesb. Hi-Fi Prototypec. Lo-Fi Prototyped. Yes, wireframes need to look like a completely finished product | b. Hi-Fi Prototype


A single question element extracted from the Coursera's web:
<div class="rc-FormPartsQuestion" aria-labelledby="WyLsh0XqEemmTA56ZlZejA-legend">
   <div id="WyLsh0XqEemmTA56ZlZejA-legend" class="rc-FormPartsQuestion__row" data-test="legend">
      <div class="rc-FormPartsQuestion__numberCell">
         <h3 class=" css-6ecy9b" aria-hidden="true"><span>1</span>.</h3>
         <span class="screenreader-only"><span>Question 1</span></span>
      </div>
      <div class="rc-FormPartsQuestion__contentCell" id="prompt-WyLsh0XqEemmTA56ZlZejA">
         <div class=" css-4s48ix">
            <div class="rc-CML" dir="auto">
               <div data-testid="cml-viewer" class="css-1kgqbsw">
                  <p><span><span>Which of the following are among key tasks that were identified?</span></span></p>
                  <div>
                     <span><span></span></span>
                     <figure role="figure" contenteditable="false" tabindex="0"><img src="https://d3c33hcgiwev3.cloudfront.net/imageAssetProxy.v1/cFCt9EXqEemFOA6Hm29iNA_d8e5a45cdc401c6709f94f5621cbde15_Q3P1.png?expiry=1717891200000&amp;hmac=MGuyCnj4ZzBRWWnYfgVhyQWTObvgL9xoRzBoWcJz9Ww" alt="" data-asset-id="cFCt9EXqEemFOA6Hm29iNA" class="cml-image-default undefined css-8qpjjf"></figure>
                  </div>
                  <p><span><span></span></span></p>
               </div>
            </div>
         </div>
      </div>
      <div class="rc-FormPartsQuestion__pointsCell">
         <div class="css-1mvreox"><span class=" css-6ecy9b"><span>1 point</span></span></div>
      </div>
   </div>
   <div class="rc-FormPartsQuestion__row pii-hide" data-testid="form-part">
      <div class="rc-FormPartsQuestion__numberCell"></div>
      <div class="rc-FormPartsQuestion__contentCell">
         <div class="rc-FormPartsMcq" role="group" aria-labelledby="WyLsh0XqEemmTA56ZlZejA-legend">
            <div class="css-18k2uoc">
               <div class="rc-Option">
                  <label class="_1oyudm1w cui-Checkbox cui-active">
                     <span class="_1e7axzp">
                        <svg class="_ufjrdd" aria-hidden="true" focusable="false" viewBox="0 0 24 24" role="img" aria-labelledby="RadioUncheckedc536e17c-9146-44c3-b9ce-79cb1c38e143 RadioUncheckedc536e17c-9146-44c3-b9ce-79cb1c38e143Desc" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" style="fill: rgb(102, 102, 102); height: 24px; width: 24px;">
                           <path d="M12 2C6.48 2 2 6.48 2 12s4.48 10 10 10 10-4.48 10-10S17.52 2 12 2zm0 18c-4.42 0-8-3.58-8-8s3.58-8 8-8 8 3.58 8 8-3.58 8-8 8z" role="presentation"></path>
                        </svg>
                     </span>
                     <input class="_htmk7zm" name="WyLsh0XqEemmTA56ZlZejA" type="radio" tabindex="0" value="0.23852303460841262">
                     <span class="_bc4egv p-x-1s font-weight-normal">
                        <div class=" css-4s48ix">
                           <div class="rc-CML rc-Option__input-text" dir="auto">
                              <div data-testid="cml-viewer" class="css-1kgqbsw">
                                 <p><span><span>Check map, Help, Activate function “Robbery”</span></span></p>
                              </div>
                           </div>
                        </div>
                     </span>
                  </label>
               </div>
            </div>
            <div class="css-18k2uoc">
               <div class="rc-Option">
                  <label class="_1oyudm1w cui-Checkbox cui-active">
                     <span class="_1e7axzp">
                        <svg class="_ufjrdd" aria-hidden="true" focusable="false" viewBox="0 0 24 24" role="img" aria-labelledby="RadioUncheckedea7f5299-8e99-41ea-f7fb-760595a3f422 RadioUncheckedea7f5299-8e99-41ea-f7fb-760595a3f422Desc" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" style="fill: rgb(102, 102, 102); height: 24px; width: 24px;">
                           <path d="M12 2C6.48 2 2 6.48 2 12s4.48 10 10 10 10-4.48 10-10S17.52 2 12 2zm0 18c-4.42 0-8-3.58-8-8s3.58-8 8-8 8 3.58 8 8-3.58 8-8 8z" role="presentation"></path>
                        </svg>
                     </span>
                     <input class="_htmk7zm" name="WyLsh0XqEemmTA56ZlZejA" type="radio" tabindex="0" value="0.7149666518536051">
                     <span class="_bc4egv p-x-1s font-weight-normal">
                        <div class=" css-4s48ix">
                           <div class="rc-CML rc-Option__input-text" dir="auto">
                              <div data-testid="cml-viewer" class="css-1kgqbsw">
                                 <p><span><span>Check map, Create a post, Log Out</span></span></p>
                              </div>
                           </div>
                        </div>
                     </span>
                  </label>
               </div>
            </div>
            <div class="css-18k2uoc">
               <div class="rc-Option">
                  <label class="_1oyudm1w cui-Checkbox cui-active">
                     <span class="_1e7axzp">
                        <svg class="_ufjrdd" aria-hidden="true" focusable="false" viewBox="0 0 24 24" role="img" aria-labelledby="RadioUncheckedd4ea4dc1-2638-4c68-8013-dd3c5a13d516 RadioUncheckedd4ea4dc1-2638-4c68-8013-dd3c5a13d516Desc" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" style="fill: rgb(102, 102, 102); height: 24px; width: 24px;">
                           <path d="M12 2C6.48 2 2 6.48 2 12s4.48 10 10 10 10-4.48 10-10S17.52 2 12 2zm0 18c-4.42 0-8-3.58-8-8s3.58-8 8-8 8 3.58 8 8-3.58 8-8 8z" role="presentation"></path>
                        </svg>
                     </span>
                     <input class="_htmk7zm" name="WyLsh0XqEemmTA56ZlZejA" type="radio" tabindex="0" value="0.5749646870867715">
                     <span class="_bc4egv p-x-1s font-weight-normal">
                        <div class=" css-4s48ix">
                           <div class="rc-CML rc-Option__input-text" dir="auto">
                              <div data-testid="cml-viewer" class="css-1kgqbsw">
                                 <p><span><span>Customize automatic functions, Help, Log Out</span></span></p>
                              </div>
                           </div>
                        </div>
                     </span>
                  </label>
               </div>
            </div>
            <div class="css-18k2uoc">
               <div class="rc-Option">
                  <label class="_1oyudm1w cui-Checkbox cui-active">
                     <span class="_1e7axzp">
                        <svg class="_ufjrdd" aria-hidden="true" focusable="false" viewBox="0 0 24 24" role="img" aria-labelledby="RadioUnchecked857f214b-e4df-40c8-e810-a3c5baaa0044 RadioUnchecked857f214b-e4df-40c8-e810-a3c5baaa0044Desc" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" style="fill: rgb(102, 102, 102); height: 24px; width: 24px;">
                           <path d="M12 2C6.48 2 2 6.48 2 12s4.48 10 10 10 10-4.48 10-10S17.52 2 12 2zm0 18c-4.42 0-8-3.58-8-8s3.58-8 8-8 8 3.58 8 8-3.58 8-8 8z" role="presentation"></path>
                        </svg>
                     </span>
                     <input class="_htmk7zm" name="WyLsh0XqEemmTA56ZlZejA" type="radio" tabindex="0" value="0.603798411956308">
                     <span class="_bc4egv p-x-1s font-weight-normal">
                        <div class=" css-4s48ix">
                           <div class="rc-CML rc-Option__input-text" dir="auto">
                              <div data-testid="cml-viewer" class="css-1kgqbsw">
                                 <p><span><span>Change security code, Create a post, Check recent events</span></span></p>
                              </div>
                           </div>
                        </div>
                     </span>
                  </label>
               </div>
            </div>
         </div>
      </div>
      <div class="rc-FormPartsQuestion__pointsCell"></div>
   </div>
</div>

My problem is that it worked fine for almost question but still doesn't work for some case like the above case, i have do some console writeline code to check that:
// Worked
testQs-This example would most likely be an example of (choose the BEST response):-
sheetQs-This example would most likely be an example of (choose the BEST response):a. Wireframesb. Hi-Fi Prototypec. Lo-Fi Prototyped. Yes, wireframes need to look like a completely finished product-
sheetAns-b. Hi-Fi Prototype-
testAns-Wireframes-
testAns-Hi-Fi Prototype-
key-Hi-Fi Prototype- // If it run correctly, the key line should be logged to the console
testAns-Lo-Fi Prototype-
testAns-Yes, wireframes need to look like a completely finished product-
// Doesnt work
testQs-Which of the following are among key tasks that were identified?-
sheetQs-Which of the following are among key tasks that were identified?a. Check map, Help, Activate function "Robbery"b. Check map, Create a post, Log Outc. Customize automatic functions, Help, Log Outd. Change security code, Create a post, Check recent events-
sheetAns-a. Check map, Help, Activate function "Robbery"-
testAns-Check map, Help, Activate function "Robbery"-
testAns-Check map, Create a post, Log Out-
testAns-Customize automatic functions, Help, Log Out-
testAns-Change security code, Create a post, Check recent events-


Show us your actual code...

You'll need to include some code for proper help. Both the C# code and the html code for the site that displays the text.

Do not just check for missing words, but also for HTML tags and elements. When you inspect the strings in the debugger, do you see anything special?

Check the quotes, in the HTML I do see “Robbery”, and you seem to check for "Robbery"  (you seem to check for 0x002, while it seems to contain 0x201C and 0x201D

Looks like the problem is in your html:
<p><span><span>Check map, Help, Activate function “Robbery”</span></span></p>

"Check map, Help, Activate function “Robbery”" does not equal "Check map, Help, Activate function "Robbery"".
You have different quotes in your html from what you have in your text file (” vs "). Update the html (or the text file) so that both sets of quotes match.

Thank you very much, its worked, the difference between the ” and " is so tricky to found if i only see the result from the terminal. I really appreciate your help
